# Pig script warning, while trying to do any FOREACH i am getting this warnings

Tags: apache-pig

```
grunt> a = load '/user/horton/flightdelays_clean/part-m-00000' using PigStorage(',');
```

> 2016-10-12 15:22:25,593 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - fs.default.name is
>   deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS

```
grunt> b = group a by $0;
grunt> c = foreach b generate COUNT($0);
```

> 2016-10-12 15:22:40,244 [main] WARN 
>   org.apache.pig.newplan.BaseOperatorPlan - Encountered Warning
>   USING_OVERLOADED_FUNCTION 1 time(s). 2016-10-12 15:22:40,248 [main]
>   WARN  org.apache.pig.newplan.BaseOperatorPlan - Encountered Warning
>   IMPLICIT_CAST_TO_BAG 1 time(s).

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a field as an argument to a function that requires some type but the field is another type.
Try this:

```
grunt> b = group a by $0;
grunt> c = foreach b generate COUNT(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
c = foreach b generate COUNT($0);
```

Should be

```
c = foreach b generate COUNT(a);
```